# ASP.NET MVC 3 project templates do not show in VS 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010:

Version 10.0.30319.1 RTMRel
Platform Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.0.30319 RTMRel

1. I installed files which I downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1491.
2. I cleared out the template cache located at "[ProgramFile x86]\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplatesCache" and then run devenv.exe /installvstemplates from the visual studio command line.
3. I am sure that I use Net.Framework 4.0. I have seen this many times :)

But MVC 3 Templates have not showed yet!
How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled MS VS 2010 and repeated all actions and all become okay:).